I am attempting to set up SFML in VSC but it isn't linking properly
The following is my tasks.json:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\Programming\\C++\\mingw64\\bin\\clang++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\GraphTest.exe",
                "-DSFML_STATIC",
                "-I",
                "C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\Programming\\C++\\SFML-2.6.1\\include",
                "-L",
                "C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\Programming\\C++\\SFML-2.6.1\\lib",
                "-lopengl32",
                "-lfreetype",
                "-lgdi32",
                "-lwinmm",
                "-lws2_32",
                "-lsfml-network-s",
                "-lsfml-graphics-s",
                "-lsfml-window-s",
                "-lsfml-system-s"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ]
}

This is my main.cpp:
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window;

    return 0;
}

When I attempt to compile this I get the following error messages:
C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Programming/C++/mingw64/bin/ld: C:/Users/Name/AppData/Local/Temp/main-5549e3.o:C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Business\C++GraphTest/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow()'
C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Programming/C++/mingw64/bin/ld: C:/Users/Name/AppData/Local/Temp/main-5549e3.o: in function `main':
C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Business\C++GraphTest/main.cpp:90: undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am using static linking (already tried dynamic,) I'm using SFML 2.6.1 for c++17 64bit, and clang++ to compile.
In c_cpp_properties.json I already checked the include path was set up properly.
When attempting dynamic linking previously, I changed the required file names in tasks.json and copied the .dll files to the project folder.
I have tried adding additional #includes in main.cpp, and reordering the -l files in tasks.json
I have also attempted to fill out RenderWindow completely (VideoMode(size), "Name"), but that throws up similar errors regarding VideoMode.

"C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\Programming\\C++\\SFML-2.6.1\\lib", You should use pacman to install all of your open source libraries. VSCode recommends installing your compiler using msys2. I suspect you installed the wrong binaries for your compiler. The correct ones should have a .a extension for the libraries not .lib

In c_cpp_properties.json I already checked the include path was set up properly. c_cpp_properties.json is used for Intellisense mode in the editor. It has nothing to do with building your code or linking.

where did you get your SFML libraries from? Are they built with the same compiler as you're using to build your program?
